# Closing Bat file with Bat file without additional .txt file

Tags: batch, batch-file

So, I have 2 .bat files (lets call them A and B)
A is the Main Programm and B is running in the Background.
But now i want to Close B via typing in A "Close B"
I want it to work without additional files.
I tried using "call" but it didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Start B with certain title, like this:

```
start "_operationB_" /MIN cmd /c call cmdB.bat
```

And in A you can locate B by its title and close it:

```
taskkill /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq _operationB_"
```

Comment: You could also use the `title` command from B to make it more distinguished, and you can set the title at any point within the batch file, so you could, for example, use A to close B only if it's at a certain point where it might stall (`title This_might_stall`).